# Difference between "temp=*q" and "temp->link=*q"

Tags: c, list, data-structures

While learning coding for Linked List, I came across these two things and could not understand difference between them, leaving me perplexed. The book, which I have been learning from, explains "temp=*q" in the part where we are adding a new node at the end of a Linked List.

> So, if the list is not empty, i.e.the condition `if(*q==NULL)` fails, then the next part would execute. Now `temp` is made to point to the first node in the list through the statement
>
> `temp=*q;`
>
> Now using **temp** we have traversed though the entire linked list using the statememnts:
>
> `while (temp->link!=NULL)
>      temp=temp->link;`

Later in the coding where a new node is being added to at the beginning of the list, I see:

> Now we need to make the `link` part of the node point to the existing first node. This has been achieved through the statement
>
> `temp->link=*q;`

Now the problem is I can't differentiate between these two codes. Are not they playing the same role in both the contexts? Relevant to mention, `temp` is a temporary node used for all the updation works on the list and `*q` is the starting node.

Comment: The first one sets the _first_ element of the list, the second one sets the _second_ element of the list.

Comment: I'm guessing the language is C, and editing the question tags.  If that's wrong, you can edit the question tags to correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First Example

Before you start using `temp` to traverse the list in the first example, you have a memory layout like this:

[image: three-node list]

Then you create a local variable, `temp`.  Let's say that initially it is the null pointer:

[image: temp pointing to NULL]

Then you set `temp` equal to `*q`:

```
temp=*q;
```

This makes your memory layout look like this:

[image: temp pointing to first node]

Then you execute this loop:

```
while (temp->link!=NULL) temp=temp->link;
```

This steps `temp` along the nodes of the list until it points to the last node.  So in my example diagram (which has three nodes), `temp` will first move to the second node in the list:

[image: temp pointing to second node]

And then it will move to the third node in the list:

[image: temp pointing to third node]

The loop ends here because now `temp->link` is `NULL`.

It should be clear that both the first assignment (`temp=*q`) and the assignment in the loop (`temp=temp->link`) don't change the structure of the linked list.  These assignments just make `temp` point to different nodes in the list.

### Second Example

In your second example, you're adding a new node at the front of the list.  So you set `temp` to point to a new node:

[image: temp pointing to new, unlinked node]

Then you execute this statement, which you found confusing:

```
temp->link=*q;
```

Here is is the memory layout after executing that statement:

[image: new node points to prior first node]

It should be clear, **unlike the first example**, `temp` points to the same node after the assigment that it did before the assignment.

The next step (not shown in your question) will be to update `*q` to point at the new node, with this statement:

```
*q = temp;
```

That will change the memory layout to this:

[image: *q points to new node]

Now you don't need `temp` any more.  Presumably you will return from the function that has `temp`, and it will disappear, leaving your memory like this:

[image: final, four-node list]

Comment: Excellent explanation. It removed my confusion. Thanks a lot +1

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not playing the same role.

First of all, both your functions to insert in the beginning and end are taking a *pointer to pointer* to the first node, so the pointer representing representing the linked list (your head pointer) can be updated accordingly.

When inserting in the end of the linked list, you first do `temp = *q` to make `temp` point to the first node in the list. *There are no links set here, this is just a normal pointer copy.* Then, you traverse till the end, and insert a new node at the end.

When inserting in the front, you first allocate space for a new node, make `temp` point to it, and make *temp's link* point to the head of the list. This is done with `temp->link = *q`. *A link is set here.* And then, the head itself is changed, so `*q = temp`.